# Why is matching 1250 strings against 90k patterns so slow?

Tags: linux, grep

My strings are file paths like `s/14/11/13/15/n7ce49B_235_25ed2d70.jpg`; my patterns are quite simple ones, all like `n7ce49B_.+`.

I'm running `GNU grep 2.6.3` under *Debian 6.0.10* on *Dell DL360G7* server (I mention it just to give a sense of this machine perfomance) with 15k HDDs, and this command: `time LC_ALL=C grep -E -f path_to_patterns_file path_to_strings_file` just can't complete - server swaps too badly.  With 20k patterns it takes more than 3 hours.

That seems unreasonable to me.

Per comment request, there is the files: [file paths](https://pastebin.com/xAsRxFFg) [20k patterns](https://pastebin.com/YXq2h8k6)

One may also test and adjust the number of input lines and patterns with:

```
xxd -p /dev/urandom | fold -sw 100 | head -n 1250 |
  grep -Ef <(xxd -p /dev/urandom | fold -sw 10 | head -n 20000)
```

Comment: your title has `90k`, the description has `20K` patterns

Comment: Well, 90k is my original input size and that makes my machine swap so hard that I have to kill that grep. Then I tried to split this to 20k files and it still works horribly... But you right that my description is inconsistent.

Comment: in case if it's not critical, you could share links to that files (on some free file host service). I would test them on my system/grep now

Comment: Please clarify whether or not the server might have been overtaxed (doing some other resource hungry tasks) during the `grep`.

Comment: @agc no, it's a pretty relaxed frontend with 6 physical cores with HT and typical LA under 1.

Comment: One can reproduce with `xxd -p /dev/urandom | fold -sw 100 | head -n 1250 | grep -Ef <(xxd -p /dev/urandom | fold -sw 10 | head -n 20000)`. It looks like the time is spent compiling the regexps and allocating a lot of memory. With `-F` instead of `-E`, it's instantaneous.

Comment: For that matters, not that `n7ce49B_.+` is equivalent to `n7ce49B_.`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I had to turn extented syntax on to get this patterns to work. I guess that should be possible with basic syntax too?

Comment: I find that with BRE it's just as bad. -F is for fixed string. `n7ce49B_.+` or `n7ce49B_.` is for `n7ce49B_` followed by at least one character which you can't do with `-F`. It looks like it's a lot better with busybox grep than with GNU grep.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, If compiling the regexps is the bottleneck, it seems like changing your code's first `head -n 1250` to a lower number, say *1*, or *100* would be similarly slow.  Yet your code with those numbers completes in *10* seconds or less.

Comment: @agc, it seems you're right. Then, I don't understand why `grep` would need more memory to process more lines of input (as I can see memory usage growing continuously while it works).

Comment: It looks like only GNU `grep` has the memory issue. The `grep` of ast-open is reasonably fast here.

Comment: While it takes forever and uses a lot of memory with GNU grep 2.25 from ubuntu 14.04, it's instantaneous with GNU grep 3.0.25, so you could always upgrade.

Comment: yay, I encountered bug in one of the core GNU utilities!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You ran into a performance problem in older versions of GNU grep ([bug#22357](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22357)) that was addressed [by this commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=290ca116c9172d97b2b026951fac722d3bd3ced9), released in 2.28 though that change [introduced some regressions](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25655), so you would want to get GNU `grep` 3.0 or newer instead.